# Is there a way to gracefully fail when a custom tag is missing?

Tags: master-page, asp.net, custom-control

I need to do some specific CSS changes to the publishing section of my SharePoint site when the logged in user is a specific account. To do this, I have created a custom control `<HideInterfaceForSpecifiedUser /`>. This works fine.

However, since I link this control to the master page and it is part of my solution, all areas where the control is linked fail to load when the solution is not deployed. I can live with this, but it is a bit annoying during testing. Is there a better way to do it, so not all pages which are linked to this master page fail to load when the custom control is not deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good solution is to use Delegate Control on master page. The delegate control will initialize your custom control on fly. Check here for details :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463169.aspx